# float() argument must be a string or a number, not 'BarContainer'

Tags: python, casting, visualization

I wanted to fix the number of decimal points for barcontainer (python object)

```
ax = sns.countplot(...)
for i in ax.containers:
    # typecast
    ax.bar_label(i,)
```

The i has a type "barcontainer". In the visualization, it's a float number of 8 decimal points. I want to round the float number to 4 decimal points. How can I do that?

update: I tried to typecast in float but it is showing "float() argument must be a string or a number, not 'BarContainer'" then tried first convert into str then float, but failed again

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I tried to typecast in float but it is showing "float() argument must be a string or a number, not 'BarContainer'" then tried first convert into str then float, but failed again

Answer (score 0):

The fmt argument specifies a format string that is used to format the label text.
Here's an example of how you can use the fmt argument to round the bar labels to 4 decimal places:

```
ax = sns.countplot(...)
for i in ax.containers:
    ax.bar_label(i, fmt="%.4f")
```

This will format each label as a floating-point number with 4 decimal places, rounding as necessary.